# Update List property from another list value based on the condition using linq c#

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have two lists:

```
public static class CsvList
{
    private static readonly List<CsvLogData> csvList= new List<CsvLogData>();

    public static List<CsvLogData> csvData { get => csvList; }
}

public class CsvLogData
{
    public string SiteUrl { get; set; }
    public string SiteTitle { get; set; }
    public string KeywordMatched { get; set; }
}

public static void FilterList()
{
    List<string> Keyword = new List<string>() { "test1", "test2", "test3", "test4" };
    
    var filtered = CsvList.csvData.Where(x => Keyword.Any(y =>(x.SiteTitle.ToLower().Contains(y)) || 
    (x.SiteUrl.ToLower().Contains(y))));
}
```

I was able to filter one list by another based on condition but what I wanted is, as soon as  'where' condition was satisfied I want to store that Keyword from Keyword list in csvData List. So I tried writing a Linq query but I don't understand how to store that keyword in the csvData.KeywordMatched property

What I tried writing:

```
foreach (var item in filtered.Where(x => Keyword.Any(y => (x.SiteTitle.ToLower().Contains(y)) || (x.SiteUrl.ToLower().Contains(y)))))
{
   item.KeywordMatched = ?
}
```

How to store that matching keyword in the property?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that via `SelectMany` operator. Since LINQ is about querying, not modification, I propose to create new instances:

```cs
var query = 
    from csv in CsvList.csvData
    from k in Keyword
        .Where(k => (csv.SiteTitle.ToLower().Contains(k)) || 
            (csv.SiteUrl.ToLower().Contains(k)))
    select new CsvLogData 
    { 
        SiteUrl = csv.SiteUrl,
        SiteTitle = csv.SiteTitle,
        KeywordMatched = k 
    };

var result = query.ToList();
```